# Error when Passing Array from Php to AS3

Tags: php, arrays, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am new to AS3, and I had tried a few times to pass an array from php to AS3. But i can't manage to do it. 
But i managed to narrow down the problem to 1 set of code, so wondering what do i need to change it.

When the function is this

```
function Asandler(event:Event){


var responseVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(event.target.data);
           nobed = responseVariables.nobed ;
            zip = responseVariables.zip;
           Location = responseVariables.Location;
            price = responseVariables.price;
           }
```

It returns an error Error #2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs.

But when i change it to

```
function Asandler(event:Event){


    s1.test.text=event.target.data
               }
```

It displays array with no problem, inside the dynamic text field.

php echo part

```
 $solutions = array();

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
        {

            echo "nobed=".$solutions[1]=$row['nobed'];
        echo "&zip=".$solutions[2]=$row['zip'];
      echo "&Location=".$solutions[3]=$row['Location'];
      echo "&price=".$solutions[4]=$row['price'];


        }
```

Test Data string

```
nobed=100&zip=100&Location=100&price=100
```

New try, testing it with dynamic text field, it display the whole string.

```
var receivedValue:String = event.target.data.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/mg, "");
var test:Array = receivedValue.split(",");

s1.test.text =test[0];
```

But not too sure how to split the string up.

Comment: Can you post what your actual generated string looks like? You're not encoding it at the server side, so my suspicion is that this is an unencoded character issue.

Comment: Also, if you have more than 1 row, you'll be getting an invalid string for two reasons: the end of price and the start of nobed will have no delimiter, and the keys will be duplicated.

Comment: Ok, i will put it in the answer right now, but the error occur before i type in anything. When the page just load, the error 2101 pops up straight away

Comment: So is the string entirely empty? It may not like that either. Just add a quick check before the code to make sure it isn't empty.

Comment: The weird thing is, it isn't when i trace event.target.data or if i put it into a dynamic text field.

Comment: But when i try to parse it as URLVariables or Array, that error appear before i do anything.

Comment: That test data should be fine. I can only assume that somehow it isn't what you think it is (e.g. Contains newlines, an error message, a BOM, etc.)

Comment: because it is only 4 items, so i don't really want to parse them in an XML. Not sure what else i can do, as i am pretty new to this. And i have to split the array up, as i have to parse them to the next .as file and feed the texts into boxes.

Comment: Shot in the dark: try `new URLVariables(event.target.data as String);`

Comment: @zamnuts just tried, same error.I have no idea why it is doing this. But it is shouting error at this line var responseVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(event.target.data);

Comment: But i have been having weird issue with php array into AS3, the first item from the first Variable becoming null, and when it loops 2nd time the first variable merged into the last variable.

Comment: @Clarklight You could try and see exactly what is in the string by loading it into a ByteArray and dumping hex: http://pastebin.com/ptDrJSGy Notice that string length is 19 while bytes available is 22. this may help uncover hidden characters you're not seeing. an ascii table to compare the results against: http://ascii.cl/

Comment: I will give that a go, it seems like that when i use any Var inside the function, AS3 tries to load data from the variables straight away.

Comment: I managed to made some progress, the data is parsing through but not splitting up, can anyone give me some advice? Or maybe i am still being completely wrong, not too sure. I editted the question.

Comment: @Clarklight if it is ampersand delimited, why are you splitting by comma?

Comment: Haha sorry i was too tired, maybe too stupid at the same time lol, didn't see that at all. I put that in with var receivedValue:String = event.target.data.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/mg, "");
var test:Array = receivedValue.split("&"); i can display the individual part of the result in a dynamic text field. Now i have to figure out how to parse that onto the next as file